# Insert Values with special Characters using PDO

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

I have problems inserting values with special Characters in names like "Renè". The Name "Renè" shows up in my Database like this: "RenÃ©"

I tried to change the field in the database to "utf8_general_ci" which didn't help, so its probably something in my code.

The name comes from a JQuery Ajax Request and I am able to echo this name inside the called .php file correctly.

```
$fullname = $_POST['playersearch'];
echo "<div class='n_ok'><p>Inserted $fullname successfully (PlayerID is $id)</p></div>";
```

I connect to my DB using PDO and I specified the UTF-8 charset:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass,array('charset'=>'utf8'));
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

The insert into the DB happens here:

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO PlayerCards (playerName, buyPercentage) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $fullname);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $buypercentage);
```

Why does it look so weird in my MySQL Database?

Comment: Instead of `array('charset'=>'utf8')` use `array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")`

Comment: You're welcome. You may as well delete the question. I don't need to put in an answer unless you really want me too and to close the question, cheers

Comment: I want to keep it here for others who have similar problems. I coped this original pdo script from a php help page, so probably others did this as well and will wonder one day.

Comment: Ok, I will formulate an answer.

Comment: What's wrong with setting it on the DSN, eg `mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the manual:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php**

It specifies that the character set syntax in PDO be used as:

```
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
);
```

Also read the warning on that page:

> **Warning**
>   The method in the below example can only be used with character sets that share the same lower 7 bit representation as ASCII, such as ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8. Users using character sets that have different representations (such as UTF-16 or Big5) must use the charset option provided in PHP 5.3.6 and later versions.

Therefore and in your case, by changing

```
array('charset'=>'utf8')
```

to

```
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
```

if you wish to run an initialisation command after connecting; more on this in comments below.

---

As stated by Phil in comments; *there is no need to run an initialisation command after connecting.*

Using `mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8` can also be used.

*The 4th argument (options array) is for specific driver options (usually PDO attributes) set on the connection.*

Thank you Phil.

Comment: What's wrong with setting it in the DSN? No need to run an initialisation command after connecting.

Comment: @Phil TBH Phil, that I did not know and will be glad to add it to my answer, quoting your comment. However, is `charset=utf8` not equal to what OP was using `'charset'=>'utf8'` and failed?

Comment: No. The DSN string is used in connection. The 4th argument (options array) is for specific driver options (usually PDO attributes) set on the connection.

Comment: @Phil Thank you for the added information Phil, which I have added in my answer, *cheers*